# Навигация в webbrowser

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Всем доброго времени суток!
Подскажите как реализовать? На форме webbrowser, при создании формы в нем открывается определенный сайт:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://mysite.com/');
end;`
```

мне нужно чтобы при заходе только на определенную страницу сайта (допустим  mysite.com/help) в программе открывалось второе окно (TForm2) со справкой.

Comment: Что пробовали? Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: У вебброузера есть событие при загрузке, там пишете проверку на адрес, если он совпадает, то открываете в новой форме

Comment: вы про OnNavigateComplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);

begin
  if (string(webbrowser1.LocationURL) = 'http://mysite.com/help') then /* тут ещё может быть адрес 'http://www.mysite.com/help' или ещё слэш на конце может быть*/
  begin
    form2.show;
  end
end;
```

Comment: спасибо,то что нужно!